# Change color of android:activatedBackgroundIndicator

Tags: android, colors

Can I change the default color (blue) of the attr android:activatedBackgroundIndicator?

I am developing an application for target 18 and for minimun 11.

Thank you

Comment: Are you trying to change this app-wide, or only for one container?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Here is a way to change it on your theme:

Update your theme to apply your custom style on the `activatedBackgroundIndicator` attribute (here the parent theme is Holo Light but you can of course change it):

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/list_activated_background</item>
    </style>
```

In your "drawable" resource folder, create the XML file list_activated_background and define your new background indicator, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
   <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@color/OrangeLight" />
   <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@color/OrangeDark" />
   <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/OrangeDark" />
   <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />  
</selector>
```

Then just be sure you are calling your custom theme in the manifest file with `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` in this case for example.

Answer (score 6):

On Lollipop and above, you have the option of setting `colorControlActivated` in your theme instead:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material">
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/your_color</item>
</style>
```

This approach works because the Material Theme's `activatedBackgroundIndicator` selector uses `?attr/colorControlActivated` for the activitate state as seen in [themes_material.xml](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/themes_material.xml#L132) and [activated_background_material.xml](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable/activated_background_material.xml#L19).

Note that Yoann Hercouet's answer is correct and still works in Lollipop.